# what does the default struts handler for DELETE do

Tags: java, struts2, struts, struts-1

Struts seems to have a default handler doDelete for the DELETE HTTP method. The servlets I have implemented does not use any DELETE method. However, the DELETE method does show up when I perform a method query using curl.

I'd like to know the default behavior of the default servlet which implements doDelete. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know too much about Struts2 and their use of Actions. But if you are defining your own servlets you will have the same behavior as Struts1 with ActionServlets. An ActionServlet subclasses from HttpServlet, and does not override the `doDelete` method. Here is the [open source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#HttpServlet.doDelete%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) for the `doDelete` method in `HttpServlet`:

```
protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String protocol = req.getProtocol();
    String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_delete_not_supported");
    if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
    }
}
```

The default implementation of the `doDelete` method on servlets returns an error (which you can verify by sending a `DELETE` request to a sample servlet, with a tool like [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en)).

Comment: Minor detail. I think OpenJDK implements only the JSE and it doesn't cover Servlets. That seems like the reference implementation of the 2.5 Servlet standard.

Comment: @madth3 - not necessarily minor. AFAIK the source for the Servlet API was made available at the same time as the JSE. In any case I've changed my answer to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Struts 2 supports REST via two available in the core [restful mappers](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/restfulactionmapper.html), but you must enable them first.
Or with the [Struts 2 REST plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html).

In both cases you must first configure Struts 2 to enable REST support.